# jQuery prepend the traversed element's next children

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

How do I only get the next element of the element I've already traversed to for a jQuery prepend.

For each .element-to-insert-into I'd like to prepend that element's next children.

Below does not work. I believe I'm not using "this" correctly:

```
jQuery('.element-to-insert-into').prepend(jQuery(this).next('.parent-element').children('child-id-like-to-prepend'))
```

Comment: **Notice:** if `child-id-like-to-prepend` is an id, it should be written with `#` first: `#child-id-like-to-prepend`

Comment: sorry for the confusion! in the class name I wrote id as it was in the sentence above...it was supposed to be I'd and in "I would".

Comment: Understood, no problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an [`each`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) loop:

```js
jQuery('.element-to-insert-into').each(function(index, element) {
  var $current = $(element);
  $current.prepend($current.next('.parent-element').children('#child-id-like-to-prepend'));

  // as ids are meant to be unique, you could just prepend the targeted id:
  $current.prepend($('#child-id-like-to-prepend'));
});
```